# Potassium chloride for electrolyte replenishment instead of monopotassium phosphate

Tags: exercise, sports, hydration, potassium, electrolytes

Is there a reason that potassium chloride is not a good source of potassium to use for electrolyte replenishment (Gatorade has monopotassium phosphate for example and Liquid IV has dipotassium phosphate).

The Wikipedia page says "In medicine, monopotassium phosphate is used for phosphate substitution in hypophosphatemia." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopotassium_phosphate#Applications)

Comment: I've since discovered that Gatorade organic has potassium chloride and no phosphate ingredients which makes it seem like it may be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 4):

In solution, none of these original chemical salts matter because they dissociate entirely. All you have once you add water are ions in solution. Potassium ions in solution are potassium ions in solution, it doesn't matter what they were previously bound with before dissolving.

Phosphate, however, is itself an [important ion in biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypophosphatemia), and when you refer broadly to ["electrolytes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolyte#Physiological_importance), phosphate is included. Presumably that's why these formulations include some phosphate salt. The reasons for using a potassium salt of phosphorus are likely just by convenience and relative concentrations.